# Still snapping to a feature that has been removed

Tags: openlayers, snapping

I'm using a LineString to split a Polygon into two on a OpenLayers map.

I draw the LineString, detect the intersection points, remove the LineString and the original Polygon and then I add the two new Polygons.

After this is done the Snapping class I have active for other tools is still snapping to the LineString I drew to split, event though it has been removed.

Has anyone had this happen before and do you have a solution to remove the ghost Snapping?

```
drawSource.on('addfeature', (e: VectorSourceEvent) => {
  const cutLine = e.feature?.getGeometry() as LineString;
  const coordinates = cutLine.getCoordinates();

  const turfCutLine = turf.lineString(coordinates);
  const allFeatures = drawSource.getFeatures();

  allFeatures.forEach((feature) => {
    // We only want to look at polygons
    if (!isPolygon(feature)) {
      return;
    }

    const polygonCoordinates = (feature.getGeometry() as Polygon).getCoordinates();
    const polygon = turf.polygon(polygonCoordinates);

    const intersectionObject = lineIntersect(turfCutLine, polygon);

    // Line cuts polygon in excactly two places
    if ((intersectionObject as { features: Array<TurfFeature> }).features.length === 2) {
      if (polygonCoordinates.length !== 1) {
        return;
      }

      try {
        const intersectA = (intersectionObject as { features: Array<TurfFeature> })
          .features[0].geometry.coordinates;
        const intersectB = (intersectionObject as { features: Array<TurfFeature> })
          .features[1].geometry.coordinates;
        const { polygonA, polygonB } = splitPolygonByLine(
          polygonCoordinates,
          coordinates,
          [intersectA[0], intersectA[1]],
          [intersectB[0], intersectB[1]]
        );

        // Remove original polygon and the cutLine, then add the two new polygons
        drawSource.removeFeature(feature);
        addPolygonToLayer([polygonA], drawSource);
        addPolygonToLayer([polygonB], drawSource);
      } catch (e) {
//...
      }
    }
  });
  e.feature && drawSource.removeFeature(e.feature);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Just a guess - maybe you need to save the edits?

Comment: How is the snap interaction constructed?

Comment: `const snap = new Snap({ source: drawSource });`
`map.addInteraction(snap);`

Comment: Similar logic is working with no problems here https://codesandbox.io/s/snap-forked-dpsq0n?file=/main.js

Comment: There is not enough code to reproduce the problem. Please edit your question and add all relevant code, so problem can be reproduced.